Does Passwords.app have a CLI?
It's possible to access passwords stored in Keychain by using the security CLI tool. Is there an equivalent CLI tool for Passwords.app released in macOS Sequoia?

The Passwords app is just a new user interface to the same password database. There is no change in the CLI.

In this case, how do I search for an account with a given "label"? I've tried both find-generic-password and find-internet-password subcommands with either -l, -a and -s match flags and couldn't find the dummy entry I created for testing.

This is really another question, but what is your test entry and what do you mean by a "label"? As well as the entry, please show the command you're using to search for it.

Thanks, I will ask another question so that I can format it properly.

I added this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/476377/how-can-i-use-security-to-search-for-entries-in-passwords-app
