How can I use `security` to search for entries in Passwords.app?
This is a followup question to Does Passwords.app have a CLI?
Since security is the CLI for Passwords.app, how can I search for a given password by searching the "Website, App or Label" field? I created a dummy entry for testing, with the value Label for the main field, and tried to find it with a few different security invocations:
security find-internet-password -l Label
security find-internet-password -a Label
security find-generic-password -l Label
security find-generic-password -a Label

Neither of these can find the test password I added for testing.
Password creation screen:

Password display screen:


You may be trying to search for an iCloud Keychain item. There is no command-line interface to that and never was any. If you need shell access to those items, you'll have to copy them to a local keychain.

I just created this password in Passwords.app to try and retrieve it with security. I guess you are right about there being no CLI for iCloud Keychains, but I disabled iCloud syncing of Passwords, deleted and recreated the dummy password and can't find it in in Keychain Access, neither in the login nor in the iCloud Keychains.
IOW, I can't see passwords created via Passwords.app on Keychain Access.

My earlier comments were misleading because of my flawed understanding of what Passwords does. It's true that Passwords doesn't change the underlying structure of the password database. It's a replacement for the Passwords settings pane in Sonoma. But it's not a replacement for Keychain Access. The latter is an interface to legacy file-based keychains and also to the new-style Data Protection keychain, which is called "Local Items" if iCloud Keychain is not active, and "iCloud Keychain" if it is.
The security command only has access to file-based keychains. The Passwords app only has access to the Data Protection keychain. So if you create a keychain item in Passwords, security won't see it, and vice versa. Apple hasn't provided a CLI to Data Protection.
Although Keychain Access is deprecated in Sequoia, it's still hidden away at /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Keychain Access.app. You can still use both it and security to manage your file-based keychains as in the past. But Apple wants you to put the past behind you, as you'll see if you launch Keychain Access in Sequoia.
See:
TN3137: On Mac keychain APIs and implementations (developer.apple.com)
Does Sequoia’s Password app change keychains? (eclecticlight.co)

Thanks for the detailed answer and the links. I guess I'll have to move the API keys I currently keep in Keychain Access and query via security in the terminal to 1Password instead of Passwords.app


Keychain Access is deprecated in Sequoia

Really? Where does Apple say Keychain Access is deprecated?
